# Finding numbers in a command output and save it as variables

Tags: bash, string

In a bash script, I wish to get some numbers from the output of a command and store them in variables. An example of the command output:

```
25 results [22 valid, 2 invalid, 1 undefined]
```

I would like to save the four numbers in the previous command-output as variables called `results, valid, invalid, undefined`.

Comment: No, only spaces in between as shown.

Comment: please try below and let me know so I can tweak it if it did not work for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say that the output of this command is saved in a file called `output.txt`, then you can use the commands `awk` and `grep` as follows:

```
results=$(grep results output.txt | awk '{print $1}')    
valid=$(grep valid output.txt | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d [])
invalid=$(grep invalid output.txt | awk '{print $5}' | tr -d [])
undefined=$(grep undefinedoutput.txt | awk '{print $7}' | tr -d [])
```

Include these four lines in your bash where it fits.

Instead, you can only use `awk` to find a matching pattern, as follows:

```
results=$(awk '/results/{ print $1 }' output.txt)
valid=(awk '/valid/{ print $3 }' output.txt | tr -d [])
invalid=(awk '/invalid/{ print $5 }' output.txt | tr -d [])
undefined=(awk '/undefined/{ print $7 }' output.txt | tr -d [])
```

Comment: With the exception of your minor typo ($1 in the second line should be $3}, this works!

Comment: The grep seems unnecessary, right? Since the output is already a single line.

Comment: @nabeelj `grep` + `awk` almost always means the `grep` is unnecessary anyway since `awk` can do pattern matching itsel

Comment: The grep may be too permissive if any of those words appear elsewhere in the output.

Answer (score 7):

Since you want to store multiple separate values, I assume that you want to store them in an array:

```
$ str='25 results [22 valid, 2 invalid, 1 undefined]'

$ readarray -t arr < <( grep -E -o '[0-9]+' <<<"$str" )
```

This reads the output of `grep` into an array called `arr`. The `grep` command will output each separate number found in `$str` on its own line by matching the extended regular expression `[0-9]+` against the string and extracting each match.  `grep` reads the string from a "here-string", and `readarray` reads the `grep` result using a process substitution.

The values may then be used as

```
$ printf 'value: %s\n' "${arr[@]}"
value: 25
value: 22
value: 2
value: 1
```

or, to look at individual values, use e.g. `"${arr[0]}"`, `"${arr[1]}"`, etc.  The array contains `"${#arr}"` values.

```
results=${arr[0]}
valid=${arr[1]}
invalid=${arr[2]}
undefined=${arr[3]}
```

---

To read *directly* from a command:

```
readarray -t arr < <( mycommand | grep -E -o '[0-9]+' )
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there any alternative to the command `readarray `. I don't have this command in my system! `is readarray ` equivalent to `read`. Thanks!

Comment: @Goro Your `bash` is older than release 4.0 (2009)?

Comment: @ Kusalananda. Thanks for the response. No it is `4.2.46(2)-release`

Comment: @Goro In that case, I see no reason why `readarray` would not be a valid command, unless you are in fact running some other shell that is not `bash`.

Comment: @Goro Ah, just managed to find that the `-t` option to `readarray` was added in `bash` 4.3.  It strips the delimiter (newlines by default) off from the read data.  Without `-t`, each array element would have a trailing newline.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your output is in a variable called output, you can split it with sed, keeping just the spaces and digits, to allow you easily split the "words" into an array:

```
tim@host:~$ res=($(sed 's/[^0-9 ]*//g' <<< $output))
tim@host:~$ printf "results: %s\nvalid: %s\ninvalid: %s\nundefined: %s\n" "${res[@]}"
results: 25
valid: 22
invalid: 2
undefined: 1
```

Comment: Don't put variable expansions into the `printf` format string. Use placeholders like `printf 'results: %s\nvalid: %s\n ...etc..' "${res[@]}"`

Comment: is that to protect against variables that contain characters that printf would interpret?

Answer (score 2):

You could use parameter expansion to replace everything that's not a digit with a space, then use word splitting to read the result into your variables:

```
str='25 results [22 valid, 2 invalid, 1 undefined]'
read results valid invalid undefined <<< ${str//[![:digit:]]/ }
```

The expansion results in something like

```
$ echo "${str//[![:digit:]]/ }"
25          22        2          1
```

and `read` does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

On any POSIX shell:

```
a='aja 25 results [22 valid, 2 invalid, 1 undefined]'

set --                         # clean the list of argumnets.
while [ ${#a} -gt 0 ]; do      # while a is not empty, loop.
    b=${a%%[0-9]*}             # extract leading characters that are not digits (if any).
    a=${a#"$b"}                # remove those from the source variable.
    b=${a%%[^0-9]*}            # extract the leading digits.
    set -- "$@" ${a:+"$b"}     # until a empty, add numbers to the list.
    a=${a#"$b"}                # remove the digits from the source string.
done

printf '<%s> ' "$@"; echo      # print the list of values.
```